# How to display profile picture.Facebook-php, graph-api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I have this code and I am trying to display my own picture, but I don't know what I am doing wrong and I can't get basically my own picture. any advice? many thanks.

```
<?php

    $user= $facebook->getUser();

    $user_graph = $facebook->api('me/');

    if($user):{

       var_dump($user_graph);
   echo '<h1> Hi and welcome  ', $user_graph['first_name'],'</h1>';
   echo '<h1> my picture  ', $user_graph['picture'],'</h1>';
    }
   else:
   {
    echo 'please log in';
   }
   endif;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing 'me' with your actual facebook ID.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following link :-

```
$user_graph = $facebook->api('me/');
```

by:-

```
$user_graph = $facebook->api('me/?fields=id,name,picture');
```

When you want to get the url of profile picture use

```
$user_graph['picture']['data']['url']
```

If you don't know the explanation of that, Comment me to demonstrate that.

Comment: Hey Sir thanks for your reply, I will try it out and let you know .Cheers.